# Importing data to SAS from a csv file

Tags: csv, input, sas, raw-data, character-limit

I'm working with a .csv export of a workout app.  It records the date, time, exercise, reps, weight, and comments.  Like many .csv files, its a little messy.

Example:

```
Date,Time,Exercise,# of Reps,Weight,Comments12/23/2014,14:52,Hip Abduction,30,180,12/23/2014,14:52,Hip Abduction,30,180,12/23/2014,14:51,Inverse Bench,15,95,12/23/2014,14:51,Abb Twist,30,100,12/23/2014,14:51,Pull-Ups,5,170,12/23/2014,14:27,Squat,15,135,12/23/2014,14:27,Squat,15,13512/23/2014,14:27,Squat,15,13512/23/2014,14:27,Deadlift,15,135,12/23/2014,14:27,Crunch,30,170,12/23/2014,14:27,Crunch,30,17012/23/2014,14:27,Crunch,30,17012/23/2014,14:26,Bench,15,135,12/23/2014,14:26,Bench,15,13512/23/2014,14:26,Bench,15,135,etc...
```

I've been able to import the data, however, it is limiting the number of characters to 8; as seen in the date and exercise variables.

SAS Code:

```
DATA strength;
    infile 'C:\Users\user\Google Drive\strength.csv' DLM = ',' DSD;
    input Date $ Time $ Exercise $ Reps Weight Comments;
    if date = 'Date' then delete;   *removes first obs - the csv header;
RUN;

PROC PRINT data = strength;
    title 'Simple Work Out Log Export';
RUN;
```

SAS Output:

```
Obs      Date      Time     Exercise    Reps    Weight    Comments

     1    12/23/20    14:52    Hip Abdu      30      180         .
     2    12/23/20    14:52    Hip Addu      30      180         .
     3    12/23/20    14:51    Inverse       15       95         .
     4    12/23/20    14:51    Abb Twis      30      100         .
     etc...
```

I don't have a lot of experience working with .csv files, but I did try using

```
input Date $ Time $ Exercise $ 12. ....
```

but that didn't work because different exercises have different length names.

How would I go about importing the full date and exercise name for a raw .csv data file like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's also possible to write a slightly more complex input statement that does what you want without using an informat statement:

```
input date :mmyydd10. time :time. Exercise :$32. reps :8. weight :8.;
```

You can then apply date and time formats:

```
format date mmddyy10. time time.;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the length of the variables in an `INFORMAT` statement.

Try this before your `input`.

```
informat var1 $X1. var2 $X2.;
```

substituting `var1` and `var2` for the variable names and `X1` and `X2` with the length.

You can read in the date and time as actual date and time types with the `informat`.  You can also specify the read to start on line 2 with `FIRSTOBS=2` on the `infile` statement.

I you can look up all of these statements in the SAS documentation online at http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/base/index.html.

Use of the `informat` statement for the date and time can be found here http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/leforinforref/64790/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0cq8eha2o93mdn1lg8n5ursmkxm.htm

Answer (score 0):

**Use colon operator here**

You see here that there is a colon preceding each informat. This colon (called an informat
modifier) tells SAS to use the informat supplied **but to stop reading the value for this
variable when a delimiter is encountered**. Do not forget the colons because without them
SAS may read past a delimiter to satisfy the width specified in the informat.

```
DATA strength;
format date mmddyy10. time time.;
    infile 'C:\Users\user\Google Drive\strength.csv' DLM = ',' DSD;
    input date : mmyydd10. 
          time : time. 
          Exercise : $50. /*Maximum length of Execrise in your dataset,have assumed 50*/
          reps : 8. 
          weight : 8.
          Comments : $50.; /*Maximum length of comments in your dataset,have assumed 50*/

    if date = 'Date' then delete;   *removes first obs - the csv header;
RUN;

PROC PRINT data = strength;
    title 'Simple Work Out Log Export';
RUN;
```